# jQuery .each and if statement, always false

Tags: jquery, html, counter

My script count elements, but if i do a **if** statement then is not correct, i need the *TRUE* only by first element, my jsfiddle code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/marco3/kE5jR/6/

I not understand is here as result "false" because counter work wihout problems...

```
if(count == 1)
```

Comment: Count == 6 - it will never be true.  It *is* correct.

Comment: count = 6, 1 =... well 1, so yeah, it's false...

Comment: what are you trying to do....

Comment: I must add class if it is first element

Comment: it looks like you are trying to do something with the first element and something else with others... in that case instead of `length` use `index()1

Comment: @MarcoP. You need to tell us what you are trying to do as this question is not at all clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/aTmKz/) the working demo:

```
    $('div.wrapper .wrapper_item').each(function (e) {
    var count = $( this).index();
    alert(count);

     if (count == 1) {
        alert('TRUE');
     } 
     else {
        alert('FALSE');
     }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u want this : You can use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kE5jR/8/)

```
$('div.wrapper').each(function (e) {
    var count = $('div.wrapper_item', this).index();
    alert(count);
    if (count == 0) {
        alert('TRUE');
    } else {
        alert('FALSE');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('div.wrapper').each() will loop through all div elements with class "wrapper".

How many of those do you have? Only 1.

So try for example $('div.wrapper div').each() or $('div.wrapper .wrapper_item').each()

to loop through all .wrapper_item elements.

Try this

> $('div.wrapper div').each(function () {
>
> ```
>  if ($(this).is(':first-child')) {
>
>        alert('TRUE');
>
>  } else {
>
>        alert('FALSE');
>  }
> ```
>
> });

Comment: I want to cunt all div's inside of div.div.wrapper, and request if first div then true.